# Каким алгоритмом решать олимпиадную задачу?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Имеется N различных сайтов для просмотра лекций, на каждом из которых время от времени проводятся технические работы. Расписание технических работ на каждом сайте известно заранее. Нужно определить, какое максимальное время в течение суток можно смотреть лекции без перерыва, возможно переключая лекции все время для этого на разных сайтах.

На вход: в первой строке количество сайтов с лекциями N (1 <= N <= 100), а в следующих   строках – расписание технических перерывов, показываемых на сайтах, в следующем формате: первое число  k (1 <= k <= 100) – количество перерывов на соответствующем сайте, далее 2k моментов времени в виде ЧЧ:ММ, разделённых пробелами – момент начала и момент окончания технической паузы).

На выход: максимальное время непрерывного просмотра лекций для в формате ЧЧ:ММ.

INPUT

2

1 00:30 01:20

2 00:30 00:40 02:40 02:45

OUTPUT

23:50

Comment: Если перефразировать задачу, то получится следующее: Дано N наборов отрезков, требуется найти длину наибольшего отрезка в их объединении. Какой именно момент тут вызывает затруднения?

Comment: @Yaant Ну для начала как считать входные данные. Каждый раз разное количество сайтов и технических перерывов. В массив или как?

Comment: Ну да, в динамический массив. Впрочем, тут уже как будет удобнее лично Вам. Если есть желание героически преодолевать трудности, то можно, например, вообще извратиться и так и работать со строками.

Comment: @Yaant можете помочь с самим кодом. Как считать я уже придумал, а вот с реализацией проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Разверните исходные данные в массив (Время - Изменение). Начало перерыва - Изменение=1, окончание - Изменение=-1. Отсортируйте по времени и просчитайте сумму с накоплением. Только в те периоды, где она равна количеству сайтов, смотреть будет нечего, т.е. всё то время, пока сумма меньше, есть что посмотреть.