# Найти свободные строки в промежутках дат

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, как найти свободные `classrooms.classroom_id` для определенного `services.service_id`: такие, что не находятся в `services_classrooms`, или такие, что даты определенного `services.service_id`: `services.service_start` и `services.service_end` не пересекаются с датами других `services.service_id` связанных с `classrooms.classroom_id` находящимся в `services_classrooms` (Рис. 1)

[image: Рис. 1] Рис. 1

---

```
mysql> show columns from classrooms;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| classroom_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| classroom    | varchar(10) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> show columns from services_classrooms;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| classroom_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| service_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> show columns from services;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| service_id    | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lesson_id     | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| worth_id      | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_end   | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| service_start | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: А чем данный вопрос отличается от этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663919/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-mysql ?

Comment: Структура какая то странная. Я бы понял, если бы сервис занимал определенную комнату в определенную дату. Или если бы за сервисом была закреплена строго одна комната (без связующей таблицы многие-ко-многим services_classrooms). Но сейчас получается, что один сервис может быть сразу в нескольких комнатах во все свои дни

Comment: @Mike, поменял структуру, и не смог подогнать тот ответ. В моем исполнении у одной строки `classrooms.classroom_id` могли быть все `services.service_id`

Comment: А зачем вы ее поменяли, какая цель создания таблицы services_classrooms. что такое service, почему он действует на интервале дат и как он соотносится с комнатами. он всегда проходит в одной комнате, или сразу в нескольких или то в одной комнате, то в другой (но в разные дни)

Comment: @Mike, хороший вопрос "зачем". Уже понял мою ошибку с этой смежной таблицей. **UPD**: вспомнил зачем добавлял ее, чтобы избежать `NULL` в строках `services`, т.е. если `classroom` еще не назначена. Или это того не стоит?

Comment: А зачем избегать NULL ? в нем нет ничего страшного

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661154/229437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант без `UNION` и вложенных запросов. Так же, дополнительно проверяет на пересечение аудитории текущего сервиса с другими сервисами в таблице.

```
SELECT
    c.classroom_id,
    c.classroom
FROM services s
-- перебираем все аудитории
JOIN classrooms c ON (1 = 1)
-- ищем все сервисы привязанные к аудиториям
LEFT JOIN services s1 ON s1.classroom_id = c.classroom_id
-- сервис для которого ищем свободные аудитории
WHERE s.service_id = 1
-- группируем полученные записи по аудиториям
GROUP BY c.classroom_id, c.classroom 
-- ищем минимальное значение в группировке по условиям
-- если минимальное значение равно 1, то аудитория доступна
HAVING MIN(CASE
            -- если у сервиса уже назначена эта аудитория
            WHEN s.classroom_id = c.classroom_id AND s.service_id = s1.service_id
                THEN 1
            -- если аудитория заданная у сервиса s1 не пересекается по датам с сервисом s
            WHEN (s.service_start >= s1.service_end OR s.service_end <= s1.service_start) AND s.service_id <> s1.service_id
                THEN 1
            -- если у аудитории нет ни одного назначенного сервиса
            WHEN (s1.service_id IS NULL)
                THEN 1
            -- иначе будет 0
            ELSE 0
           END) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Подумав, после прочтения комментариев @Mike, я решил изменить структуру связи между таблицами `classrooms` и `services` допустив `NULL` в поле `classroom_id`.

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM classrooms;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| classroom_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| classroom    | varchar(10) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM services;
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| service_id    | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lesson_id     | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| teacher_id    | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| classroom_id  | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| worth_id      | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| service_start | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| service_end   | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Сделал такой запрос исходя из новых таблиц:

```
SELECT 
table1.classroom_id, 
c.classroom 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            s.classroom_id 
        FROM 
            services s 
            JOIN services s1 ON s1.service_id = '$service_id' 
        WHERE 
            (
                s1.service_start > s.service_end 
                OR s1.service_end < s.service_start
            ) 
            AND s.classroom_id IS NOT NULL
    ) as table1 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            s.classroom_id 
        FROM 
            services s 
            JOIN services s1 ON s1.service_id = '$service_id' 
        WHERE 
            (
                (
                    s1.service_start BETWEEN s.service_start 
                    AND s.service_end
                ) 
                OR (
                s1.service_end BETWEEN s.service_start 
                AND s.service_end
                )
            ) 
            AND s1.service_id <> s.service_id
    ) as table2 ON table1.classroom_id = table2.classroom_id 
    JOIN classrooms c ON table1.classroom_id = c.classroom_id
WHERE 
    table2.classroom_id IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT 
    c.classroom_id, 
    c.classroom 
FROM 
    services s 
    RIGHT JOIN classrooms c USING(classroom_id) 
WHERE 
    s.service_id IS NULL
```

Данный запрос выводит нужные `classroom_id` включая тот, который уже числится за `service_id`